# UIScrollView and auto layout issue

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, autolayout

Ok, I use this code below to set big content size:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    self.theScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, 10000);
}
```

I also use auto layout. So my scroll view has UIView that is configured as below:

[image]

[image]

So it means that after rotating the screen the UIView will be directly in the centre of view.

FYI: my scroll view stretch in the screen:

[image]

But I have another problem right because of auto layouts my content size does now work right now.

Comment: try [self.theScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, 10000)]; instead of self.theScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, 10000);

Comment: With auto layout scroll view, the content size is calculated based on the subviews, you can't set it. Your content size will grow with the content